# Ansible : How to extract a nested dictionary value from a JSON response in YAML

Tags: ansible, yaml

In a playbook, we do a query to a password vault through it's web api.  The problem is that the value I am after is inside a dict that is itself inside another dict, and I have no idea how to get that value from the nested dict using yaml syntax.  Here is the content of the web request:

```
[localhost] => {
    "cache_control": "no-store",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content_length": "190",
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "cookies": {},
    "cookies_string": "",
    "date": "Tue, 10 Sep 2019 18:00:18 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": null,
            "body_format": "raw",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "X-Vault-Token": "<token>"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "http://<serverip>:8200/v1/cubbyhole/ansible",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "json": {
        "auth": null,
        "data": {
            "ansible_password": "<thepassword>"
        },
        "lease_duration": 0,
        "lease_id": "",
        "renewable": false,
        "request_id": "77f067f4-8deb-538b-26d2-8b70f8c83e71",
        "warnings": null,
        "wrap_info": null
    },
    "msg": "OK (190 bytes)",
    "redirected": false,
    "status": 200,
    "url": "http://<serverip>:8200/v1/cubbyhole/ansible"
}
```

The data I want to retrieve is the password that is located in the "data" dict, and which is itself a part of the json dict.

Every syntax I tried does not seem to be able to go deeper than the json dict.  Any clue on how to proceed?

The playbook look like:(the debug part is the last attempt to try to get the password value)

```
  - name: get password
    uri:
      url: "http://<serverip>:8200/v1/cubbyhole/ansible"
      method: GET
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        X-Vault-Token: "{{ansible_token}}"
    register: secret_result

    debug:
          msg: "{{item.key['data']}}"
        with_dict: 
          - '{{ secret_result }}'
```

I have looked at many posts, but most were different enough that their solution didn't apply. I also tried tons of syntax derived from those posts,(with_dict, with_subelements) to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ secret_result.json['data']['ansible_password'] }}"
```

Comment: Upon seeing the answer I was sure I had tried that, and it always returned that "data" was not a dict value,  but I guess I was wrong as your code works perfectly and return the password.    Thanks!